# Need help finding button id/class etc to click

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, jss

I'm writing a Python script to enter MS Teams and join a class based on a schedule, and have very little to no knowledge of markup languages/ js.

[image]

This "Join" button is what i want to click.

When i click inspect on it, I get (Highlighted in blue):

[image]

My code to click the button:

```
driver.get(physics)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class=""]').click()
```

need help finding the class/id/ anything to be honest, to click the button.

The rest of my code: [code](https://pastebin.com/1GkWi04j)

Comment: Hey for `xpath` it contains as `//tag-name[@class="value"]` you have not given any value in your case it should be class-name

Comment: @BhavyaParikh what value am i supposed to write though, is where my problem likes

Comment: you have to give class-name from tag input

Comment: @BhavyaParikh can you just type what code i'm supposed to put, and explain that as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the details of the button from below the screenshot.
But it is not recommended to use the classes for the same as they might be repetitive on the entire page.

The button is highlighted in the inspector tools.
Note: class root-160 is a dynamic class and you might not wanna use it. It will change per meeting/pages.

[Screenshot of button component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWECa.png)

Comment: Imported to note you can copy the xpath by clicking the element and searching for copy -> xpath.